# Sorting and re-numbering values in Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following Python dictionaries:

```
road_dict = {0:[1L,2L], 1:[3L], 2:[4L,5L]}
dist_dict = {1L: 4.1, 2L: 2.1, 3L: 4, 4L: 2.1, 5L: 6}
num_dict = {0:[2,4], 1:[5], 2:[1,3]
```

The first one, road_dict, has road IDs as keys and home IDs associated as values. The second, dist_dict, has the same home IDs as keys and their distance along the road as values. The third, num_dict, has the same road IDs as keys and number associated with the same homes as values.

I am trying to re-number these homes based on their distance along the road. **A simple version of what I'm looking to get is this**:

```
new_dict = {0:[4,2], 1:[5], 2:[1,3]}
```

*For key 0, the order of numbers has switched because home ID 1L is farther along the road than 2L. This also means that 4 now pertains to 1L and 2 pertains to 2L.*

I have some other issues, however, due to the way my dictionaries are separated. I'm looking for an approach that will the information together in one dictionary, so I can more easily keep track of which home number belongs to which home ID.

**Ultimately, what I'm looking to achieve is this**-- 1 is the index of a field I'm trying to update (with the new, sorted number):

```
final_dict = {1L:{1:4}, 2L:{1:2}, 3L:{1:5}, 4L:{1:1}, 5L:{1:3}}
```

**A missing piece I just realized could be useful** This creates a dictionary with a simple incrementation of the order of each home along the line. I think this belongs with my original question. :

```
another_dict = {0:[2,1], 1:[1], 2:[1,2]}
```

**UPDATE** I tried the following code using the following dictionaries, but things are still not sorting correctly. While the homes are sorted by distance and ready to be numbered sequentially, I am also looking to keep the set of existing numbers and switching them around to be in the right order based on distance. This code allows each home to keep their existing number regardless of distance order.

```
i_road_dict = {421: [32L, 33L, 34L], 422: [9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L], 423: [66L, 67L, 72L, 73L, 76L], 623: [2L], 624: [0L], 627: [3L, 4L], 629: [86L], 317: [50L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 70L, 71L, 74L, 75L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 85L, 87L, 88L]}

i_num_dict = {421: [15, 19, 21], 422: [31, 33, 35, 39, 43, 31, 29, 25, 23, 19, 15, 41, 49, 47, 9, 7, 11, 13, 17], 423: [11, 13, 17, 23, 27], 623: [1], 624: [13], 627: [9, 5], 629: [7], 317: [109, 151, 45, 47, 143, 141, 133, 131, 101, 95, 91, 81, 57, 63]}

i_distance_dict = {0L: 61.488059367717, 2L: 8.021516228782936, 3L: 45.52003866488311, 4L: 25.20730241437668, 9L: 157.844303290623, 10L: 162.61477713824982, 11L: 177.70675687888885, 12L: 194.7672626115625, 13L: 205.85748324109224, 14L: 151.29798366856477, 15L: 147.66380499017282, 16L: 119.9462825595851, 17L: 114.98507682692828, 18L: 98.45714293590342, 19L: 87.46475300724273, 27L: 209.53486929892026, 28L: 232.3460547737345, 29L: 239.89698687340757, 32L: 71.13973224724995, 33L: 90.16514887960331, 34L: 106.48078486409304, 35L: 30.04092989941455, 36L: 39.961250890703326, 37L: 53.44419657185303, 38L: 83.59339524297145, 39L: 85.66697660333085, 50L: 549.0312971771257, 63L: 753.3816549180551, 64L: 225.80699058127138, 65L: 237.74936014259308, 66L: 58.12282403458027, 67L: 63.3770825337218, 70L: 708.6717387628081, 71L: 704.5817839747034, 72L: 87.27533124959758, 73L: 113.56828281454557, 74L: 658.1701619456403, 75L: 654.8787862943727, 76L: 137.46561448886376, 81L: 501.846856735727, 82L: 478.70973384256945, 83L: 456.2651041053348, 85L: 407.21753873616143, 86L: 34.367967658321774, 87L: 286.4419958357572, 88L: 317.3584642656698}
```

After using this code:

```
i_homes = []
for road_id, home_ids in i_road_dict.items():
    i_home_numbers_on_road = i_num_dict[road_id]
    for home_id, home_number in zip(home_ids, i_home_numbers_on_road):
        home = {}
        home['home_id'] = home_id
        home['home_number'] = home_number
        home['road_id'] = road_id
        home['distance'] = distance_dict[home_id]
        i_homes.append(home)

i_sorted_dict = {}
for road_id in i_road_dict:
    i_homes_on_road = [home for home in i_homes if home['road_id'] == road_id]
    i_ordered_homes = sorted(i_homes_on_road, key=lambda h: h['distance'])
    i_sorted_dict[road_id] = i_ordered_homes
```

I got this result:

```
i_sorted_dict = {421: [{'home_id': 32L, 'home_number': 15, 'road_id': 421, 'distance': 71.13973224724995}, {'home_id': 33L, 'home_number': 19, 'road_id': 421, 'distance': 90.16514887960331}, {'home_id': 34L, 'home_number': 21, 'road_id': 421, 'distance': 106.48078486409304}], 422: [{'home_id': 35L, 'home_number': 9, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 30.04092989941455}, {'home_id': 36L, 'home_number': 7, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 39.961250890703326}, {'home_id': 37L, 'home_number': 11, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 53.44419657185303}, {'home_id': 38L, 'home_number': 13, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 83.59339524297145}, {'home_id': 39L, 'home_number': 17, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 85.66697660333085}, {'home_id': 19L, 'home_number': 15, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 87.46475300724273}, {'home_id': 18L, 'home_number': 19, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 98.45714293590342}, {'home_id': 17L, 'home_number': 23, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 114.98507682692828}, {'home_id': 16L, 'home_number': 25, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 119.9462825595851}, {'home_id': 15L, 'home_number': 29, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 147.66380499017282}, {'home_id': 14L, 'home_number': 31, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 151.29798366856477}, {'home_id': 9L, 'home_number': 31, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 157.844303290623}, {'home_id': 10L, 'home_number': 33, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 162.61477713824982}, {'home_id': 11L, 'home_number': 35, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 177.70675687888885}, {'home_id': 12L, 'home_number': 39, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 194.7672626115625}, {'home_id': 13L, 'home_number': 43, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 205.85748324109224}, {'home_id': 27L, 'home_number': 41, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 209.53486929892026}, {'home_id': 28L, 'home_number': 49, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 232.3460547737345}, {'home_id': 29L, 'home_number': 47, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 239.89698687340757}], 423: [{'home_id': 66L, 'home_number': 11, 'road_id': 423, 'distance': 58.12282403458027}, {'home_id': 67L, 'home_number': 13, 'road_id': 423, 'distance': 63.3770825337218}, {'home_id': 72L, 'home_number': 17, 'road_id': 423, 'distance': 87.27533124959758}, {'home_id': 73L, 'home_number': 23, 'road_id': 423, 'distance': 113.56828281454557}, {'home_id': 76L, 'home_number': 27, 'road_id': 423, 'distance': 137.46561448886376}], 623: [{'home_id': 2L, 'home_number': 1, 'road_id': 623, 'distance': 8.021516228782936}], 624: [{'home_id': 0L, 'home_number': 13, 'road_id': 624, 'distance': 61.488059367717}], 627: [{'home_id': 4L, 'home_number': 5, 'road_id': 627, 'distance': 25.20730241437668}, {'home_id': 3L, 'home_number': 9, 'road_id': 627, 'distance': 45.52003866488311}], 629: [{'home_id': 86L, 'home_number': 7, 'road_id': 629, 'distance': 34.367967658321774}], 317: [{'home_id': 64L, 'home_number': 45, 'road_id': 317, 'distance': 225.80699058127138}, {'home_id': 65L, 'home_number': 47, 'road_id': 317, 'distance': 237.74936014259308}, {'home_id': 87L, 'home_number': 57, 'road_id': 317, 'distance': 286.4419958357572}, {'home_id': 88L, 'home_number': 63, 'road_id': 317, 'distance': 317.3584642656698}, {'home_id': 85L, 'home_number': 81, 'road_id': 317, 'distance': 407.21753873616143}, {'home_id': 83L, 'home_number': 91, 'road_id': 317, 'distance': 456.2651041053348}, {'home_id': 82L, 'home_number': 95, 'road_id': 317, 'distance': 478.70973384256945}, {'home_id': 81L, 'home_number': 101, 'road_id': 317, 'distance': 501.846856735727}, {'home_id': 50L, 'home_number': 109, 'road_id': 317, 'distance': 549.0312971771257}, {'home_id': 75L, 'home_number': 131, 'road_id': 317, 'distance': 654.8787862943727}, {'home_id': 74L, 'home_number': 133, 'road_id': 317, 'distance': 658.1701619456403}, {'home_id': 71L, 'home_number': 141, 'road_id': 317, 'distance': 704.5817839747034}, {'home_id': 70L, 'home_number': 143, 'road_id': 317, 'distance': 708.6717387628081}, {'home_id': 63L, 'home_number': 151, 'road_id': 317, 'distance': 753.3816549180551}]}
```

At least for road 422, the homes are still out of order. I was expecting this (done by hand, so I hope I didn't miss anything) which switched the existing numbers around to sort them based on distance:

```
422: [{'home_id': 35L, 'home_number': 7, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 30.04092989941455}, {'home_id': 36L, 'home_number': 9, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 39.961250890703326}, {'home_id': 37L, 'home_number': 11, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 53.44419657185303}, {'home_id': 38L, 'home_number': 13, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 83.59339524297145}, {'home_id': 39L, 'home_number': 15, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 85.66697660333085}, {'home_id': 19L, 'home_number': 17, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 87.46475300724273}, {'home_id': 18L, 'home_number': 19, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 98.45714293590342}, {'home_id': 17L, 'home_number': 23, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 114.98507682692828}, {'home_id': 16L, 'home_number': 25, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 119.9462825595851}, {'home_id': 15L, 'home_number': 29, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 147.66380499017282}, {'home_id': 14L, 'home_number': 31, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 151.29798366856477}, {'home_id': 9L, 'home_number': 31, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 157.844303290623}, {'home_id': 10L, 'home_number': 33, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 162.61477713824982}, {'home_id': 11L, 'home_number': 35, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 177.70675687888885}, {'home_id': 12L, 'home_number': 39, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 194.7672626115625}, {'home_id': 13L, 'home_number': 41, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 205.85748324109224}, {'home_id': 27L, 'home_number': 43, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 209.53486929892026}, {'home_id': 28L, 'home_number': 47, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 232.3460547737345}, {'home_id': 29L, 'home_number': 49, 'road_id': 422, 'distance': 239.89698687340757}]
```

**another update** The issue was with the creation of final_dict as the answer provides. I adapted the sort to the new numbers and zipped with the the ordered homes instead of "homes_on_road":

```
i_final_dict = {}
for road_id in i_road_dict:
    i_homes_on_road = [home for home in i_homes if home['road_id'] == road_id]
    i_ordered_homes = sorted(i_homes_on_road, key=lambda h: h['distance'])
    #i_ordered_nums = [home['home_number'] for home in i_ordered_homes]
    i_ordered_nums = sorted([home['home_number'] for home in i_ordered_homes])
    for home, new_number in zip(i_ordered_homes, i_ordered_nums):
        i_final_dict[home['home_id']] = {sort_num_idx:new_number}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that a ``dict`` is inherently unordered. You'll probably want to convert it to a list of tuples with key/value pairs using [``dict.items()``](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) and then sort that.

Comment: So... you don't want to renumber the homes to 1,2,3... you want to keep the set of numbers on a street the same and reapply them to the houses on the street in distance order?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I want to do both. I tried testing your code on some more data and it doesn't work. I wonder if I'm adapting something incorrectly.

Comment: @user25976 The code you've edited in your question does do some sorting for me - road 784 changes from `[5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L]` to `[5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L]`, and that puts them in distance order, closest to farthest, and also in numerical order by home_number. If that holds for the other roads, then it implies I completely don't understand your question and what you are trying to achieve - and that's aside from wondering how can a home appear twice on the same road?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Ah, it looks like i appended things twice. You got that sorted? Strange...maybe something else is going on, because I did not get this result with the data I provided.

Comment: Take exactly the code you edited into your question, make a new Python file with only that in it, and add `print sorted_dict[784]` as the last line. Is the result not sorted 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, ... ? What is the result like?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Yes, the homes are sorted on the road 784 using the data I originally updated with. However, I tried breaking it down into two sides of the road to see things more clearly and things are still not sorting right. ; /

Comment: So I've just put this code into a new file and run it. Road 422 starts  `[9L, 10L, 11L, 12L...]` and after sorting it starts `[35L, 36L, 37L, 38L`. The distances in the end are `[30.04, 39.9, 53.4, 83.5`. That looks sorted to me. And you've taken out the renumbering code, so it's not renumbering them.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler That was one way to re-number them, which does work. The other way, however, which involves just switching the numbers around doesn't. I just realized this right now--see comments I posted to your answer. I hope i'm making sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be that terse? How about making a dictionary per home, with all the related information and putting those in a list:

```
from pprint import pprint

road_dict = {0:[1L,2L], 1:[3L], 2:[4L,5L]} # road_id:home_id
dist_dict = {1L: 4.1, 2L: 2.1, 3L: 4, 4L: 2.1, 5L: 6} # home_id:distance
num_dict = {0:[2,4], 1:[5], 2:[1,3]} # road_id:[house_numbers]

homes = []
for road_id, home_ids in road_dict.items():
    home_numbers_on_road = num_dict[road_id]

    for home_id, home_number in zip(home_ids, home_numbers_on_road):
        home = {'home_id':     home_id,
                'home_number': home_number,
                'road_id':     road_id,
                'distance':    dist_dict[home_id]}

        homes.append(home)

pprint(homes)
```

Gives a list, with a dictionary for each home, keeping all the things together:

```
[{'distance': 4.1, 'home_id': 1L, 'home_number': 2, 'road_id': 0},
 {'distance': 2.1, 'home_id': 2L, 'home_number': 4, 'road_id': 0},
 {'distance': 4, 'home_id': 3L, 'home_number': 5, 'road_id': 1},
 {'distance': 2.1, 'home_id': 4L, 'home_number': 1, 'road_id': 2},
 {'distance': 6, 'home_id': 5L, 'home_number': 3, 'road_id': 2}]
```

And then you get a much easier time of building things out of it:

```
new_dict = {}
for road_id in road_dict:
    homes_on_road = [home for home in homes if home['road_id'] == road_id]
    ordered_homes = sorted(homes_on_road, key=lambda h: h['distance'])
    new_dict[road_id] = ordered_homes


pprint(new_dict)
```

Gives:

```
{0: [{'distance': 2.1, 'home_id': 2L, 'home_number': 4, 'road_id': 0},
     {'distance': 4.1, 'home_id': 1L, 'home_number': 2, 'road_id': 0}],
 1: [{'distance': 4, 'home_id': 3L, 'home_number': 5, 'road_id': 1}],
 2: [{'distance': 2.1, 'home_id': 4L, 'home_number': 1, 'road_id': 2},
     {'distance': 6, 'home_id': 5L, 'home_number': 3, 'road_id': 2}]}
```

Which is your `0:4,2, 1:5, 2:1,3` intermediate result.

Although this has *reordered the homes* and not *renumbered them*. But then what does it mean to renumber home 5 on street 2, when it's the only home on street 2? Assuming they go 1, 2... on each street:

```
new_dict = {}
for road_id in road_dict:
    homes_on_road = [home for home in homes if home['road_id'] == road_id]
    ordered_homes = sorted(homes_on_road, key=lambda h: h['distance'])
    for position, home in enumerate(ordered_homes):
        home['home_number'] = position + 1

    new_dict[road_id] = ordered_homes

pprint(new_dict)
```

Which gives:

```
{0: [{'distance': 2.1, 'home_id': 2L, 'home_number': 1, 'road_id': 0},
     {'distance': 4.1, 'home_id': 1L, 'home_number': 2, 'road_id': 0}],
 1: [{'distance': 4, 'home_id': 3L, 'home_number': 1, 'road_id': 1}],
 2: [{'distance': 2.1, 'home_id': 4L, 'home_number': 1, 'road_id': 2},
     {'distance': 6, 'home_id': 5L, 'home_number': 2, 'road_id': 2}]}
```

Which has put the houses to show in the order they are physically in (by distance), and renumbered them sequentially from closest to furthest on a road-by-road basis.

[Edit: maybe correction]

Edit: Is this what the final_dict should be?

```
# order the homes by distance
# pair up the homes by position with the home_numbers by distance

final_dict = {}
for road_id in road_dict:
    homes_on_road = [home for home in homes if home['road_id'] == road_id]
    ordered_homes = sorted(homes_on_road, key=lambda h: h['distance'])
    ordered_nums = [home['home_number'] for home in ordered_homes]

    for home, new_number in zip(homes_on_road, ordered_nums):
        final_dict[home['home_id']] = {1:new_number}

pprint(final_dict)
```

Giving:

```
{1L: {1: 4}, 2L: {1: 2}, 3L: {1: 5}, 4L: {1: 1}, 5L: {1: 3}}
```

Comment: Can you explain the correction you made? Also, any thoughts on how to get it into the final format I'm looking to have?

Comment: The correction was when I was debating with myself over whether the final one should reorder the road lists by home_id, or renumber the home_number, or both. I started by thinking that reordering the lists was wrong, because the houses can't physically move. I finished by realising the houses aren't moving, they were listed in the wrong order, and by reordering the lists, the lists are being ordered into house order (by distance).   And I don't understand the final format you are looking to have, or what the another_dict has to do with anything.

Comment: @user25976 I've added more.

Comment: I want to accept your answer, but I'm having issues adapting it. What's happening when I apply it to my whole dataset is that the numbers are not sorting

Comment: Actually, i see now why this isn't working: The homes are re-ordered, but they are not re-numbered. For example, on road 0, house 2L still is number 4, and 1L still is number 2. What I'm looking for is not only sorting the list, but switching the numbers if needed. In this case, since 2L is closer to the beginning to the road, it should now have the number 2 and 1L should have number 4.

Comment: Your solution to number them sequentially works. But I am also looking for a solution to keep the same set of numbers, just changing the order they appear in based on the home's distance.

Comment: They are renumbered. Look at how it takes the home from the original ordering and pairs it up with a new_number from the sorted-by-distance ordering. (Staying within the set of numbers-on-that-road).

Comment: I'm looking at new_dict, where you mention it gives the intermediate result. 1L and 2L are indeed sorted by distance, but the home numbers have stayed with their respective original homes. 1L : 2 and 2L : 4. In this case 1L is farther along than 2L, so I would have expected 1L : 4 and 2L : 2. If you're talking about new_number in final_dict--this gave me a very strange output with new_numbers that don't correspond with the sorted_dict.

Comment: Yes the intermediate result doesn't renumber the houses, because there's no code there to do any renumbering. Yes I'm talking about new_number in final_dict because that's where the new numbers are assigned.

Comment: Okay, I changed final_dict a bit (see updates) and it seems to be working now...Do you think the changes I made make sense?

Comment: Yes, they make sense; you're independently sorting the home_numbers in a road, and pairing those up, whereas my code wrongly assumes that sorting the houses by distance is also sorting the numbers into order.

Answer (score 1):

Making `new_dict`:

```
>>> new_dict = dict()
>>> for ikey in road_dict:
        l = list(sorted(num_dict[ikey],key = lambda x:dist_dict[road_dict[ikey][num_dict[ikey].index(x)]]))
        print l
>>> for ikey in road_dict:
        l = list(sorted(num_dict[ikey],key = lambda x:dist_dict[road_dict[ikey][num_dict[ikey].index(x)]]))
        new_dict[ikey] = l


>>> new_dict
{0: [4, 2], 1: [5], 2: [1, 3]}
```

Making `final_dict`:

```
>>> x = 'x'
>>> for ikey in road_dict:
        for j in range(len(road_dict[ikey])):
            final_dict[road_dict[ikey][j]] = {x : new_dict[ikey][j]}


>>> final_dict
{1L: {'x': 4}, 2L: {'x': 2}, 3L: {'x': 5}, 4L: {'x': 1}, 5L: {'x': 3}}
```

I hope this works for you!

Comment: Will I have any issues in regards to pzp's comment? Also, I added a small edit with a missing piece of the puzzle that may or may not belong to this thread.